# How do I affix wires to an E27 T210 lamp holder?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a E27 T210 connection for a lamp holder, and there are no screws to fix wires into.  It is also unclear how they push in.

If this a push connection are the wires supposed to be soldered?

Comment: Some photos might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For push-in connectors, the wires do literally just push in. There is usually a gauge printed on the unit to show how much insulation to strip. Soldering stranded wire is helpful but not necessary if twisted tightly. There is usually also a tab to press with a flat screwdriver to release the wire (in case you need to remove it).

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]